# How Many Subgraphs in a Graph?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Today I came across the following pages when reading articles on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem

Apparently, there is a math problem in which for some given graph, the objective is to find the Maximum Clique (i.e. Connected Subgraph - the Clique with the most neighbors) of this graph.

I tried to think and read more about this problem, and it lead me to the following questions:

- For a given graph, do we know how many unique subgraphs exist in general? I read that "n" nodes can have  "n * (n-1)" edges - can this fact be used to find out the number of unique subgraphs that can be made in a graph?
- For a given graph, do we know how many unique partitions can be made?
- For a given graph, do we know if a maximum clique even exists?
- For a given graph, do we know how many neighbors each vertex will have in the maximum clique (if the maximum clique exists)?

By reading about this online, I can't seem to find direct answers for this questions. Does this mean that we don't even know if the maximum clique exists or what the size of this maximum clique might be - let alone identifying the maximum clique?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what you understand by a "Clique". Usually, the definition of a clique is a subgraph $H$ of a given graph $G$ such that $H$ is a complete graph (i.e. for all pairs of vertices in $H$ there is an edge between these two vertices). By this definition follows immediately that there is always a maximum clique. The hard part of this problem is, as you already mentioned yourself, identifying a maximum clique in a given graph (or just identifying the size of a maximum clique).

Comment: Also, the maximum number of possible edges in a simple and undirected graph on $n$ vertices is ${n \choose2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.